# Why is ng-model's value undefined on scope instead of an empty string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input bound to a property on scope:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="folderName">

$scope.folderName = ""
```

If input has value, folderName is equal to that string value, but if I clean the input, `folderName` is equal to `undefined` instead of empty string. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: do you use `required` on the `input`?

Comment: `if I clean the input` ? How are you cleaning object ?

Comment: @Vineet, using backspaces on a keyboard

Comment: @K.Toress, yeah, I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using validation like `required` and if the textbox is invalid that means if the `textbox` doesn't have a value then it's remains as `undefined` because its invalid that's why you getting `undefined`.

remove the `required` and check the value of it, then it will not getting the `undefined`.

this is handle by the `angular` and no need to worry about it.